# GCE/Ansible : How to create a filesystem on a new disk of a GCE instance with ansible

Tags: linux, ansible, google-compute-engine

I need to add an extra disk to an existing GCE instance using Ansible

The disk is created with the gce_pd module :

```
- name : Add new disk
  local_action:
    module: gce_pd
    instance_name: "{{ ansible_host }}"
    project_id: "{{ project_id }}"
    service_account_email: "{{ service_account_email }}"
    credentials_file: "{{ credentials_file }}"
    zone: "{{ my_zone }}"
    size_gb: 5
    mode: READ_WRITE
    name: "{{ ansible_host }}-data-disk"
  register: gce_pd
  tags:
    - add_disk
```

This task succeeds.

I then try to create an ext4 file system on the new disk :

```
#============================================================
- name : Create filesystem {{ google_disk_name }}
  filesystem:
    fstype: ext4
    # TODO : improve this
    dev: /dev/sdb
    opts: "-F -E lazy_itable_init=0,lazy_journal_init=0,discard -L {{ volume_label }} /dev/disk/by-id/{{ google_disk_name }}"
    force: yes
  become: true
  tags:
    - add_disk
    - format_disk
```

This task fails :

> FAILED! => {"changed": false, "err": "mke2fs 1.42.12
>   (29-Aug-2014)\nmkfs.ext4: **invalid blocks '/dev/sdb' on device
>   '**/dev/disk/by-id/google-my-instance-data-disk'\n", "failed": true,
>   "msg": "Creating filesystem ext4 on device '/dev/sdb' failed", "rc":
>   1}

What am I doing wrong ? The opts for the filesystem are the same as those recommended in GCE doc https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/add-persistent-disk

And if I manually execute this command, the creation of the file system succeeds !

mkfs.ext4 -F -E lazy_itable_init=0,lazy_journal_init=0,discard /dev/disk/by-id/google-my-instance-data-disk

A workaround would be to use the command module to run the mkfs.ext4 instead of using the filesystem module, but I would like to understand what is going wrong in my usage of the module.

Any help will be much appreciated

Comment: Why do you feed **device** `/dev/disk/by-id/{{ google_disk_name }}` into **opts**?

Comment: oops ! you've caught the problem. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [Konstatin Suvorov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2795592/konstantin-suvorov) who found my error in the opts: parameter :

/dev/disk/by-id/{{ google_disk_name }} was redundant with dev: parameter

So the fixed task is :

```
#============================================================
- name : Format disk {{ google_disk_name }}
  filesystem:
    fstype: ext4
    # TODO : improve this
    dev: /dev/sdb
    opts: "-F -E lazy_itable_init=0,lazy_journal_init=0,discard -L {{ volume_label }}"
    # TODO : to be discussed, useful for tests
    force: yes
  become: true
  tags:
    - add_disk
    - format_disk
```